# Is it possible to find this link text with requests?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

At the URL https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/3093543, there is a map that loads near the bottom of the page containing a ‘neighborhood’ box that says Presidio. It’s stored in a tag as `<a href="/locations/neighborhoods/479">Presidio</a>`

I'm trying to get it with this:

`profile = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/3093543").content, "html.parser")`

```
print profile.select('div[id="hover-card"]')[0].find('a').text 
    # div[id="hover-card"] is not found
```

I’m not sure if this is a dynamic variable that could only be retrieved with another module, or whether it is possible to get with requests.

Comment: No, it is not possible. It is dynamically loaded, you can check things like that by disabling javascript in the browser. Try for example selenium instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get that data via another element.
Try this:

```
profile =  BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/3093543").content, "html.parser")
print profile.select('meta[id="_bootstrap-neighborhood_card"]')[0]
```

And if needed request the map via:

```
https://www.airbnb.pt/locations/api/neighborhood_tiles.json?ids%5B%5D=ID
```

Where the ID in the above URL is given by the `neighborhood_basic_info` attribute in the first print.